# php mysql insert not working db connection is working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I have a simple insert page that seems to go through with out any errors but does not show up in db. I have read upwards of 30 diff posts on this and can not figure out what is wrong. I know the dbcon.php works as the display page pulls all the results no problem.

```
<?php
ob_start();
include('dbcon.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$Ph1=preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_POST["ph1"]);
$Ph2=preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_POST["ph2"]);
$Name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$Email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$Group=$_POST['group'];

mysql_query("insert into reps (ph1,ph2,name,email,group)
        values("$Ph1","$Ph2","$Name","$Email","$Group")");
        header('location:index.php');
}
ob_flush();
?>
```

Comment: you get no errors because you are not checking for errors, if you where mysql would tell you the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP` is a RESERVED KEYWORD. It must be enclosed with backtick,

```
insert into reps (ph1,ph2,name,email,`group`)
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

another problem is the used of `double quotes around values.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO reps (ph1,ph2,name,email,`group`) VALUES ('$Ph1','$Ph2','$Name','$Email','$Group')");
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I totally didn't think of the the reserved keyword list. Thank you. I was not worried about SQL Injection as it will be in a password protected directory and only used by one or two people but thank you for the reference link.

Comment: yes I am new, thank you for advising me on correct procedure.